# How can I find what process is trying to write to a CD that's offline?

Tags: 12.10, cd, io, ipmi

I've got a Virtual CD which can mount remote media via IPMI. After doing an install of Ubuntu 12.10 I'm getting this error every 2 sec in the syslog and on the console:

```
  [628.890722] sr 6:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to offline device
```

How can I figure out what is trying to write to that CD, it's certainly offline as I don't have any remote media mounted via IPMI right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could give it a try using `lsof` with the path to the cd drive as argument to see which process is using it.

`lsof /path/to/cd` or `lsof -a /path/to/cd`

Comment: The CD is offline and not mounted. I tried a grep for "sr0" and "cdrom" as devices, but it seems that lsof just shows mounted filesystems. This is something more bizarre than a user-space app trying to write to a CD that's engaged.